# Sharing data locally (like with sockets) between multiple programs in C++

Tags: c++, linux, stream, buffer

My goal is to **send/share data** between **multiple programs**. These are the options I thought of:

- I could use a **file**, but prefer to use my RAM because it's generally *faster*.
- I could use a **socket**, but that would require a lot of address information which is *unnecessary* for local stuff. And ports too.
- **I could ask *others* about an efficient way to do this.**

I chose the last one.

So, what would be an efficient way to send data from one program to another? It might use a **buffer**, for example, and write bytes to it and wait for the reciever to mark the first byte as 'read' *(basically anything else than the byte written)*, then write again, but *where* would I put the buffer and how would I make it *accessible* for both programs? Or perhaps **something else** might work too?

I use linux.

Comment: There is many IPC methods to be used. Please share more details of how your programs need to communicate? It it more send/recv nature or share some block of memory? It is more like stream of data or static data block?

Comment: @MichałŠrajer I'm thinking of creating "local servers" sometime which for example capture events and allow other programs to read it, but I mostly asked this question because I'm just curious about how it'd work. It wouldn't really matter if it were a stream or a static block since I don't have a real goal anyway.

Comment: Invest some time for reviewing pro/cons of each of popular IPCs. This may save you a lot of time if you pick the right one.

Comment: Fine, I'll try these IPCs now. I suppose I just don't like the name.

Comment: Never mind that, these pipes are great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about [fifos](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?fifo%204) and pipes? if you are on a linux environment, this is the way to allow 2 programs to share data.

Comment: So, what are _fifos_ and how do I create _pipes_? Oh, guess I'll just look it up.

Comment: Sorry I were editing exactly when you posted the comment, try to look for the first link

Comment: Using pipes is actually worse then using other IPC mechanisms, like for example shared memory, message queues or memory mapped files.

Answer (score 4):

The fastest IPC for processes running on same host is a shared memory.

In short, several processes can access same memory segment.

See this [tutorial](http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node27.html).

Answer (score 3):

You may want to take a look at [Boost.Interprocess](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/interprocess.html)

> Boost.Interprocess simplifies the use of common interprocess communication and synchronization mechanisms and offers a wide range of them:
>
> - Shared memory.
> - Memory-mapped files.
> - Semaphores, mutexes, condition variables and upgradable mutex types to place them in shared 
>     memory and memory mapped files.
> - Named versions of those synchronization objects, similar to UNIX/Windows sem_open/CreateSemaphore API.
> - File locking.
> - Relative pointers.
> - Message queues.

Answer (score 2):

On Linux, when using files, they are very often in cache, so you won't read the disk that often, and you could use a "RAM" filesystem like [tmpfs](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/tmpfs.txt) (actually `tmpfs` use virtual memory, so RAM + swap, and practically the files are kept in RAM most of the time).

The main issue remains **synchronization**.

Using sockets (which may be, if all processes are on the same machine, [AF_UNIX](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/unix.7.html) sockets which are faster than TCP/IP ones) has the advantage of making our code easily portable to environments where you prefer to run several processes on several machines.

And you could also use an existing framework for parallel execution, like e.g. [MPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Passing_Interface), [Corba](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corba), etc etc.

You should have a gross idea of the bandwidth and latency expected from your application.
(it is not the same if you need to share dozens of megabytes every millisecond, or hundreds of kilobytes every tenths of seconds).

I would suggest learning more about [serialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) techniques, formats and libraries like XDR, ASN1, JSON, YAML, [s11n](http://s11n.net/), [jsoncpp](http://jsoncpp.sourceforge.net/) etc.

And sending or sharing data is not the same. When you send (and recieve) data, you think in terms of message passing. When you share data you think in terms of a shared memory. Programming style is very different.

Comment: That sounds interesting. I might try it once, but I'll go for the fifos first.

Comment: Going to AF_UNIX sockets is nearly the same (except for the dissymetry of client/server ends).

Comment: I added something about serialization

Answer (score 2):

To answer your questions:

Using a file is probably not the best way, and files are usually not used for passing inner-process information. Remember the os has to open, read, write, close them. They are however used for locking (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_locking).

The highest performance you get using pipestream (http://linux.die.net/man/3/popen), but in Linux it's hard to get right. You have to redirect the stdin, stdout, and stderr. This has to be done for each inner-process. So it will work well for two applications but go beyond that and it gets very hairy.

My favorite solution, use socketpairs (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/functions/socketpair.html). These are very robust and easy to setup. But if you use multiple applications you have to prepare some sort of pool where to access the applications.

Answer (score 0):

Shared memory is the best for sharing the data between the processes. But it needs lots of synchronization and if more than 2 processes are sharing the data then synchronization is like a Cyclops. (Single eye - Single shared memory).

But if you make use of sockets (multicast sockets), then implementation will be little difficult, but scalability and maintainability is very easy. You no need to bother how many apps will be waiting for the data, you can just multicast and they will listen to the data and process. No need to wait for the semaphore (shared memory synchronization technique) to read the data.

So reading the data time can be reduced.
Shared memory - Wait for the semaphore, read the data and process the data.
Sockets - Receive the data, process the data.

Performance, scalability and maintainability will be added advantages with the sockets.

Regards,
SSuman185